# Object #<Controller> has no method addEventListener

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I am trying to create a controller to make a switch button for android since the one in Titanium doesn't have de holo look for android I need, this controller is working fine, but there is an `addEventListener` in another controller that uses my Switch controller that's throwing me a `Object #<Controller> has no method addEventListener` error. Someone told me that I had to define the addEventListener method in my switch controller but I have no clue how to do this. Any ideas?

customer.xml:

```
...    
<View>
    <Switch id="mySwitch" platform="ios"/>
    <Require id="mySwitch" platform="android" src="customSwitch" />
</View>
...
```

customer.js:

```
...
$.mySwitch.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    // magic goes in here
});
...
```

customSwitch.js:

```
$.value = false;

$.setValue = function(value){
    $.value = value;
}

var switchButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
    width                   : 97,
    height                  : 24,
    backgroundImage         : '/images/ic_switch_on.png',
    visible                 : true
});

switchButton.applyProperties($.container.switchButton);
$.container.add(switchButton);


$.container.addEventListener('click', function(evt){
    $.onClick && $.onClick({});

    var currentValue = $.value;

    if (currentValue) {
        switchButton.backgroundImage = '/images/ic_switch_off.png';
        $.setValue(!currentValue);
    } else {
        switchButton.backgroundImage = '/images/ic_switch_on.png';
        $.setValue(currentValue);
    }
});
```

Comment: If my answer below is not helpful, you need to provide a little more information about what you are trying to do. In your code there is no information what is behind `$.container` and how exactly your error message and traceback looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set event listener on container object. Probably you wanted to add event listener to `switchButton` which you created and added to container:

```
switchButton.applyProperties($.container.switchButton);

switchButton.addEventListener('click', function(evt){
    $.onClick && $.onClick({});

    var currentValue = $.value;

    if (currentValue) {
        switchButton.backgroundImage = '/images/ic_switch_off.png';
        $.setValue(!currentValue);
    } else {
        switchButton.backgroundImage = '/images/ic_switch_on.png';
        $.setValue(currentValue);
    }
});

$.container.add(switchButton);
```